# background image with tiny picture make gradient

Tags: html, css

I'm using background image property with one image of 1px*2px. The idea is to have black color on left and white on the right (1px each), because I have a picture that is black on the left and white on the right.

The result of what I did is that there is a gradient between black and white, but I don't want to because we see the gradient (gradient is bigger than picture width)

Here is the code with inline to be quick:

```
<body>
    <div class="header-wrapper" style=
    'background-image: url("../images/background.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; padding-bottom: 0px;'>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
            <div style='display:inline;'><img src="~/images/ban.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8gksgtdu/2/

I don't want to use css gradient for browser compatibility, even if customer only requested compatibility untill IE9 only.

Here is the result I have: 
[image: what I got]

Here is what I want
[image: What I would do]

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: Can you upload your image to something like http://imgur.com/, and then recreate it on http://www.jsfiddle.com/?

Comment: Can you please create a demo? Its hard to see why you would get that gradient unless your image itself has it.

Comment: If you don't want to use gradient, try gif instead png

Comment: @JamieBarker http://jsfiddle.net/8gksgtdu/2/

Comment: @Harry too http://jsfiddle.net/8gksgtdu/2/

Comment: @GermanoPlebani thanks, I've tried but it looks it's the same :-/

Comment: @clement: I don't think you can control this. Can you not use a psuedo with black background and 50% width as the container?

Comment: @Harry : I think I will make a background picture of 6px*1px, gradient will be lower

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you work with with a gradient?

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #fff 50%);
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gksgtdu/)

Comment: yes, sorry if my question is not as clear as it has to be but yes, I have gradient I don't want to! See my edited question

Comment: Please try my code first. It is exactly what you want to do because black goes until 50% with full strength and then starts with white. There is no real gradient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do, but if you want one image streched, then put

```
background-size: 100% 100%
```

which will make the image big and streched

--edit---

I see that you have one 100%, try to put two 100%

-- edit---

Putting **X-UA-Compatible** in head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7; IE=8; IE=9">
```

Seems to be fixing the background 100% issue.

Comment: Your edit won't make a difference. `background-size: 100%` is the same as `background-size: 100% 100%`. You only need to enter two values if the height and width are different.

Comment: You can introduce **X-UA-Compatible** in head tag to make the browser compatibility errors

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a background image, you can use CSS gradient to pull it off:

```css
.black-white {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #000000 50%, #ffffff 50%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%,#000000 50%,#ffffff 50%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

```html
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .black-white {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
<div class="black-white"></div>
```

Generated from [here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Comment: gradient isn't IE9 compliant. I didn't said that but it must be compliant, but yes thanks

Comment: @clement If you click the link at the bottom of my answer, it takes you to a place to generate gradients. The bottom right has a checkbox for "IE9 Support".

Comment: I really prefer using picture for compatibility, even if >IE9 is required

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use a couple more breakpoints:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #000000 0%,#000000 90%,#ffffff 90%,#ffffff 90%,#ffffff 100%);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gksgtdu/1/

Answer (score 0):

I finally used a larger picture than the first that I made (1*2 to 4*8px), it fixed mly issue - gradient still here but minimized (less width)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a pseudo class:

```css
.header-wrapper {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
}
.header-wrapper:before {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:50%;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:50;
}
.header-wrapper img {
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1Nidg46.png" /></div>
```